# Unable to find an entry point named 'sqlite3_open_interop' in DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'.

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sqlite, dll

I'm facing some problems with a SQLite dll. In my computer both debug and release versions work fine, but in the server, when I try to make any operation that connects in the database, I get the following error:

`Unable to find an entry point named 'sqlite3_open_interop' in DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'.`

I'm using .NET Framework 4.6, EntityFramework 6.0.0 SQLite 1.0.102.0.
My project has an web application ASP.NET MVC and I use a class library project to work with the database operations.
I've looked for a solution, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: SQLite with web application! will it be read only web app?

Comment: Yes, it will. Have you worked with it before?

Comment: It sounds to me that you did not install the right version of vcredist on you server.